Automate Excel data to visual Studio and automate added excel data
So I was working in an internship over the summer trying to help a non-profit company.
I tried to automate the process of data from google forms to google sheets to excel to ssms. I figured out the process to automate google forms to excel with it refeshing every 5 mins to match changes, additions and deletions.
The problem I had was making an etl process to ssms and have it automated. I used microsoft visual studio 2024 used the ssis service linked my ssms to the excel cvs and pressed run, well it worked my data moved to the ssms but that didnt answer all my problems every time I pressed run it duplicated. How can I make it so that it only adds new data rows from the excel and have it automated even if microsoft visual studio 2024 is closed or is there a direct path i can do with ssms that I dont know about where it can automate adding only new rows added to the excel. (i also created the sql server using  sql Server Express
I then couldnt figure out how to make a gridview that edit,update, and delete data from it. Using Microsoft Visual studio 2024 I was using cs and webforms. I only was able to create a website page for employees to search any column of data min of 4 lines of text and single out the users that matched the text which worked really well but I just wanted a employee system where it can edit the column data or delete rows and save it to ssms.
Feel free to answer I just want to learn from this :)

I tried making the edit part with the gridview button changes errors
tried using SSIS to make the change and automate process adding duplicate rows not new lines only.

and is there a safer method in doing all of this without spending money which was one of the bigger problems this company needed to work on.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
